# Authorisation code Flow with PKCE using Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, authorization, load, pkce

I am using jmeter for load testing and website for login is using Authorisation Code Flow with PKCE. I am getting 500 response in my signin-oidc sampler result of Jmeter Script. All other endpoints are getting 200 response.

In my Jmeter Script, I am generating code verifier and code challenge when the user clicks on login "/login" and passing on the code challenge in the request parameters of "/connect/authorize". I get the code in the response of "Account/Login?ReturnUrl.................." where I have passed username and password in request parameter. Then in "/connect/authorize/callback" as well I am passing the same codeChallenge and extracting the value of code and then passing this code value to the "/signin-oidc" alongwith the code verifier generated in "/login". All the endpoint passes except "/signin-oidc". What mistake am I making?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there a problem with your logic which is "generating code verifier and code challenge"

Make sure that it matches i.e. the one listed under [Call Your API Using the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE page](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-pkce/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce)

The equivalent JMeter code you can use in [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) would be something like:

1. For `code verifier`

   ```
   import java.security.SecureRandom;

   SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
   byte[] code = new byte[32];
   sr.nextBytes(code);
   String verifier = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(code);

   log.info('code_verifier: ' + verifier)

   vars.put('verifier', verifier)
   ```
2. For `code challenge`

   ```
   import java.security.MessageDigest
   import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

   byte[] bytes = vars.get('verifier').getBytes("US-ASCII");
   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
   md.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
   byte[] digest = md.digest();
   String challenge = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(digest);

   log.info('code_challenge: ' + challenge)
   ```

More information:

- [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)